# Actionscript AIR +show files in list

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

I'm creating an AIR project in flash and populated a list with files referenced in an external xml. Now 'm trying to populate the list with a directory's contentss, like a file browser. Below is my code

```
var myDocuments:File = File.documentsDirectory;
var fu:FileUtils = new FileUtils();
var myArray = FileUtils.GetAllFilesFromDir(myDocuments, true);

function PopulateList(event:Event):void {
    for(var i:Number = 1;i< myArray.length;i++) {
        list.addItem( myArray[i] ); // My list box
    }
}
```

FileUtils is a custom class I came across:

```
public class FileUtils
    {
        /**
         * Lists all files in a directory structure including subdirectories, except the folders themselves.
         *
         * @param STARTINGFILE File the top level folder to list the contents of
         * @param RELATIVETO File Optional If this is set all paths returned will be relative to this.
         */
        public static function ListAllFiles(STARTINGFILE:File, RELATIVETO:File = null):String
        {
            var str:String = "";

            for each(var lstFile:File in STARTINGFILE.getDirectoryListing())
            {
                if(lstFile.isDirectory)
                {
                    str+= ListAllFiles(lstFile, RELATIVETO);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(RELATIVETO!=null)
                    {
                        str+= RELATIVETO.getRelativePath(lstFile) + "\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str+= lstFile.nativePath + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }

            return str;
        }

        /**
         * Returns an array populated with File objects representing all the files in the given directory
         * including all the subdirectories but excluding the directory references themselves
         *
         * @param STARTINGFILE File the top level directory to list the contents of
         * @param INCSUB Boolean Optional Include subdirectories
         */
        public static function GetAllFilesFromDir(STARTINGFILE:File, INCSUB:Boolean = true):Array
        {
            var arr:Array = [];

            for each(var lstFile:File in STARTINGFILE.getDirectoryListing())
            {
                if(lstFile.isDirectory && INCSUB)
                {
                    for each(var subFile:File in GetAllFilesFromDir(lstFile, true))
                    {
                        arr.push(subFile);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    arr.push(lstFile);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function PopulateList(event:Event):void {
    for(var i:Number = 1;i< myArray.length;i++) {
        list.addItem( File(myArray[i]).name ); // My list box
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @casey, what seems to be your problem here?

Comment: Well the list doesn't populate, it stays blank. I thought that if I ran a for loop it would take each file found it myDocuments and list i in the list box but it's not working. I knew that would be too easy :)

Comment: see if u can add `File(myArray[i]).name` into the list

Comment: Still no luck,. I posted my edit. No errors or anything, just  nothing shows in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code in your main class to be like below and its listing me the names of all the files that i have in my documents directory.

```
  var myDocuments:File = File.documentsDirectory;
var fu:FileUtils = new FileUtils();
var myArray:Array = FileUtils.GetAllFilesFromDir(myDocuments, true);
var arrayColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

for(var i:Number = 1;i< myArray.length;i++) 
{
    var file:File = File( myArray[i]);
    arrayColl.addItem(file.name);
}
list.dataProvider = arrayColl;
```

Here the item named list is defined like so in my MXML

```
<mx:List id="list"/>
```

`addItem()` for a list object is used to add a `DisplayObject` to it. But here we will be setting the `dataProvider` property to an ArrayCollection of the names of the files.

Oh, and how was your `PopulateList` function getting invoked?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. Thanks to you I was able to get it working :) Thanks so much.

Comment: I was callingPopulateList with  button, now that this works I'm changing the code so the button lets the user browse for folder.